# Magento 2 Ubuntu Xampp/Lampp php bin/magento setup:upgrade Show Warning

Tags: magento2, ubuntu

**Magento 2 Ubuntu Xampp/Lampp** `setup:upgrade` Show Warning

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Warning  As:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib  
/php/20160303/php_intl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_intl.dll: cannot   
open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install/activate the php_intl extension.

For Windows uncomment in php.ini:

```
extension=ext/php_intl.dll
```

For php5 on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

For php7 on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```